# Can I specify a parameter that I pass with input?

Tags: input, parameters

I made my own preamble and saved it into a separate file. I include it with

```
\input{Preamble}
```

Now in the preamble there is

```
\title{MyTitle}
```

Now I want to pass MyTitle from my main document. How do I do that?

Comment: why don't you take that line out of Preamble.tex and put it in the main document? (which is more useful, if you want to share the preamble code

Comment: you can type `\title{NewTitle}` after `\input{Preamble}`

Comment: you could change the preamble to \title{\realtitle}  and then you would have to say something like \newcommand{\realtitle}{My Title} beforehand

Comment: `\title` is already storing it's argument to `\@title`. Using another `\realtitle` would introduce a third layer of macros ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is the way I did it now. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could take that line out of `Preamble.tex` and put it in the main document. Which is more useful, if you want to share the preamble code with other documents.

Incidentally it would be more idiomatic latex if you called your file `preamble.sty` rather than `Preamble.tex` then you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{preamble}
\title{my title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```